# Google Recaptcha api script keeps getting loaded first

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have included my google recaptcha api script at the end of my html before my other js files, like below:

[image]

However when inspect the network tab, the api.js file is always loaded first. Now I would expect it to be loaded last since it's at the end of the html, I've also tried `async defer` which also did not work....am I missing anything here?

P.S: this is an issue for me because my `onSubmit` function is defined in one of those js files and recaptcha fails to find it as it is loaded before my js files.

[image]